# Database function Mock is not working in c# web api unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, webapi, rest

Here is my controller method

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [Route(RouteConfig.Routes.LovList.contactStatus)]
    public IHttpActionResult ContactStatusList()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = new DBClass.HeroDb().GetList(
                            DBClass.DBConstants.ListConstants.query_Contact_Status);
            return Json(new Models.Response(
                        Models.ResponseMessages.Success,
                        result)
                     );
        }
        catch(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            return InternalServerError();
        }
        
    }
```

and this is my test case method

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void ContactStatusListTest()
    {
        
        Mock<DBClass.HeroDb> mock = new Mock<DBClass.HeroDb>();
        mock.Setup(x => x.GetList(DBClass.DBConstants.ListConstants.query_Contact_Status))
            .Returns(CreateContactList());
        var result = new ListController().ContactStatusList();
        Models.Response response = (Models.Response)result;
        Assert.AreEqual(response.Message, Models.ResponseMessages.Success);
        Assert.IsNotNull(response.Data);
    }
    public System.Data.DataTable CreateContactList()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("ContactStatus");
        DataRow row1 = table.NewRow();row1["ContactStatus"] = "Contacted"; table.Rows.Add(row1);
        DataRow row2 = table.NewRow(); row2["ContactStatus"] = "Not Contacted"; table.Rows.Add(row2);
        DataRow row3 = table.NewRow(); row3["ContactStatus"] = "Contacted"; table.Rows.Add(row3);
        return table;
    }
```

I tried to mock **GetList()** function in my test method but it is not working. Controller method is giving an Internal server error . Because conrol is going to

```
var result = new DBClass.HeroDb()
            .GetList(DBClass.DBConstants.ListConstants.query_Contact_Status);
```

this line and db object is null here. Please help as i am beginner in unit test case building .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let's set the basis first: *unit testing is different than integration testing*.

In that case this is a **unit test on the controller's method** `ContactStatusList`. You're testing only this method and you actually did things correctly by trying to mock your `HeroDb` object. Note that you decided to mock this object because **this is a dependency**.

The problem is you set up the Mock but you don't use it because in your `ContactStatusList` method you call `new DBClass.HeroDb()`.

There's a 2nd problem is that you're trying to mock a class. This is actually possible but all the class's methods you want to mock must be declared as virtual. Therefore it's actually better to mock an interface instead.

This interface should be received in the constructor of your `ListController`. On a regular execution of your Web Project inject an instance of that interface in the startup but in unit tests feed your mock to the `ListController`'s constructor.

Remember this rule: *Any dependency should be received by your controller's constructor*

Here is your interface and your DbHero class

```
public interface IDbHero
{
    IEnumerable<Contact> GetList(QueryContactStatus status);
}

public class DbHero : IDbHero
{
    public IEnumerable<Contact> GetList(QueryContactStatus status)
    {
        // Implementation here
    }
}
```

Now here's your controller:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ListController: ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHeroDb _heroDb;

    public ListController(IHeroDb heroDb)
    {
        _heroDb = heroDb ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(heroDb));
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [Route(RouteConfig.Routes.LovList.contactStatus)]
    public IHttpActionResult ContactStatusList()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = _heroDb.GetList(DBClass.DBConstants.ListConstants.query_Contact_Status);
            return Json(new Models.Response(
                        Models.ResponseMessages.Success,
                        result)
                     );
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I removed the block where you only catch the `SqlException` because anyway if you've an unhandled exception the server will return an internal server error so it's useless to catch it if you don't even log the error.
Also in the 2nd catch block I just `throw` so the server will also automatically return an internal server error. If you're in debug mode this could be handy as you'd get the full Exception returned to you but if you return `InternalServerError()` you'd get no information even in debug and you'd have to check the logs...

In the `ConfigureServices` method of your `Startup.cs` class, inject your implementation of the `IDbHero` interface. Note this is a *scoped* service, meaning a new instance will be created for each HTTP request. Personally I never inject my Database access layer as a *singleton* because this could lead to some issues depending of the way this layer is implemented. For exemple EF Core's *DbContext* is incompatible with a *singleton* pattern.

```cs
services.AddScoped<IDbHero>(_ => new DBClass.HeroDb(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbHeroConnectionString")));
```

I don't know how you handle the connection with the database because there's no mention of the connection string in your code example but I would do something like above.

Your connection string is coming from your `appsettings.json` config file

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbHeroConnectionString": "YourConnectionString"
  }
```

Now to use your mocked object in your unit test just do like this:

```cs
[TestMethod()]
public void ContactStatusList_ShouldReturnData_WhenCalled()
{
    // ARRANGE
    var mock = new Mock<IHeroDb>();
    mock.Setup(x => x.GetList(DBClass.DBConstants.ListConstants.query_Contact_Status))
        .Returns(CreateContactList());
    
    var sut = new ListController(mock.Object);
        
    // ACT
    var result = sut.ContactStatusList();
    
    // ASSERT
    Models.Response response = (Models.Response)result;
    Assert.AreEqual(response.Message, Models.ResponseMessages.Success);
    Assert.IsNotNull(response.Data);
}
```

Notice few things here:

- Your unit test name: This should show 3 things:

  - What you're testing (your method)
  - What should be the result (a result with data, a result with error, an exception raised...etc)
  - Under which conditions this result should happen

  You can for exemple test that a method is returning an error when parameters have incorrect values. **This should tested in another unit test**
- Unit tests are always in 3 parts `ARRANGE`, `ACT` and `ASSERT`. It's always a good practice to write that in each test so you can better organize your code
- `sut` means `System Under Test`: this is what you want to test, all other dependencies (like your `DbHero` layer) should be mocked.

Now the next step would be to write a unit test to test your `DbHero.GetList`.
This time you'll create a real instance (not a mock) of the `DbHero` class because this is what you want to test: **this is your *sut***.

Note that I've an intermediate level in testing so what I'm showing you is good practices I've learnt from my coworkers. But maybe some more experience developers could come up with better practices than mine.

Comment: Thankyou for clear explanation **@Jerome**. I got one step further . Now in `ListController` (_Where i am returning Json_) gives error. Should i **have to mock it as well**.

Comment: No you should **not** mock your `ListController` because this is what you want to test, testing is mock is useless because what you want to test is your **real** implementation. Mock only its dependencies (like the `IDbHero`). Set a breakpoint in your `catch` block and analyse the exception. This is an error with Json serialization, maybe a circular reference or something like this.